# How to save part of a URL as a variable using Robot Framework

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I wonder if you would be able to help

I have a page where I perform a save action and the resulting page gives me an ID in the URL

e.g. https://thiscouldbeanything.co.uk/Timesheet/Detail/115325

What I would like to do is take the 6 digit id at the end of the URL and save it as a variable for use later on in the test. I know you can use Get Location the to store the whole URL but I wondered if there was a way (probably a python keyword option) to take just the ID.

I thought maybe about a python function that would take the Get Location as an argument and then a way to chop the URL up and pass the id as a variable back, but I was unsure how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here some python code can help you get your ID in your URL

```
def getLastID(url):
    lastId=  url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    return lastId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use robot framework keyword 'Split String' of your URL.
Then, get last element of list, ${list}[-1]

Example:

```
${url}=  get location
@{splitted_url}=   Split String    ${url}   /
${id}=  evaluate   ${splitted_url}[-1]
```